# Publish agent to an author instance

Tags: adobe, aem

I have a dev author instance.  I'd like to be able to have my production environment publish just /content from the production to dev author instance.  I've used recap but I'd like to have the pages come down as they are activated.

I pointed a publish agent at the dev author instance but got this "Connection refused" message when activating content.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually a network issue. Productive servers tend to stay in the DMZ and do not have a connection to internal networks. So all communication is blocked by a firewall. This is why in AEM the reverse replication also works on pull from the author and not push from the publish. One thing I see is to develop a custom pull agent on your dev instance and an outbox agent on the productive publish, similar to the reverse replication. Another option that might work depending on where your productive author sits in the network is to have another publish agent on it that also publishes to dev.